# How to compare function value with a constant

Tags: scipy

I'm working with Python Scipy I have the next code:

```
...
t = np.linspace(0, simtime, points)  

def Vbooster90(t):
    return np.sin(t * 2 * np.pi*F_booster + 0.5 * np.pi) 

def beam(t):
    return np.sign(Vrfq(t) - Vrfq(bunchwidth)) * 0.5 + 0.5

def criteria(t):
    return np.sign(Vbooster90(t)) 

def kicker(t):
    if criteria(t) > 0:
        k(t)=beam(t)
    else:
        k(t)=0

    return k(t)
```

I have a problem with the last function `kicker(t)`. I want to compare the function `criteria(t)` with zero at each value of t, and in case if `criteria(t)` is higher than zero, I want to assign `kicker(t)` to the value of function `beam(t)` at the same t value. I'm new to Python and don't know syntax well.

Comment: Please fix all your indenting, especially in kicker() function. Also, you are trying to reference something called `k(t)`, but that's not valid syntax for referencing a vector or list (you want `[..]`), and anyway you haven't declared it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `kicker` function like following.

```
def kicker(t):
    k = 0
    if criteria(t) > 0:
        k = beam(t)
return k
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, instead of defining a function I solved it next way:

```
kicker = np.empty(points)
i = np.arange(points)
time = np.empty(points)
time[i] = i*simtime/points

for i in range(points):
   if criteria(time[i]) > 0:
    kicker[i] = beam(time[i])
   else:
    kicker[i] = 0
```